# Canonical Map of S-units into class group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, localization

In notes about Algebraic Number Theory, there is the following exercise:
Let $K$ be a number field with ring of integers $R$, and let $S$ be a finite subset of nonzero prime ideals of $R$. Show that there is a canonical exact sequence of abelian groups
$$1 \rightarrow R^* \rightarrow \oplus_{\mathfrak{p}\in S} (K^*/R^*_\mathfrak{p})\rightarrow \text{Cl}(R) \rightarrow \text{Cl}(R^S) \rightarrow 1$$

I am having trouble in finding the map $\psi: \oplus_{\mathfrak{p}\in S} (K^*/R^*_\mathfrak{p})\longrightarrow \text{Cl}(R)$.

I have tried taking $(u_\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p})_{\mathfrak{p} \in S} \in \oplus_{\mathfrak{p}\in S} (K^*/R^*_\mathfrak{p})$ to $[\prod_\mathfrak{p} u_\mathfrak{p}R^S]$ for example, or to $[\sum_\mathfrak{p} u_\mathfrak{p}R^S]$, but in the first case the homomorphism is trivial and in the second case the map doesn't seem to be  a homomorphism.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you know what $K^\times/R_{\mathfrak{p}}^\times$ looks like? Play around with some simple examples to see if you can get some intuition about the behavior of that group.

Comment: I know it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, the end of the exercise asks me to prove it

Comment: So in order to determine the map $\psi$, you just need to determine the image of 1 in each $K^\times / R_\mathfrak{p} ^\times$...